# Command for comparing two files with awk only returns last line for each match

Tags: bash, awk, git-bash

I have a bash command `$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0;}; $1 in a {print a[$1]}' file1 file2 > outputfile`.

**file1** is structured like this:

```
'resource/Autism' 'type' 'owl#Thing' .  
'resource/Alabama' 'type' 'AdministrativeArea' .  
'resource/Alabama' 'type' 'Region' .
```

**file2** is structured like this:

```
'resource/Alabama'  
'resource/Abert_Einstein'  
'resource/Autism'
```

I want my command now to compare the entries from "file2" with the entries of the first column of "file1" and if it is a match, print the whole line of "file1" in "outputfile".
For example if I have the line 'resource/Alabama' in "file2" it should print every line of "file1" where the first column equals 'resource/Alabama'.
My command however only prints the last line where it finds 'resource/Alabama'.

Can somebody please explain me what I do wrong?

Thank you very much!
Greetings, Sven

Comment: Swap the order of your input files- `awk '...' file2 file`. Think about it.

Comment: ...and if you can't figure out why thats the solution then feel free to ask a question here.

Comment: Dont forget to tell us what you try, I think it's better.

Comment: @edMorton it worked! I thought I tried to change the order of my input files before, but apparently I didnt. I had to change `{print a[$1]}` to `{print $0}` as well and yes @thanasip I am sorry I forgot the `next` statement, but my original command included it.

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can do it with `awk` but you may also try `join` which I think does exactly what you want.

Try:

```
join <(sort file2.txt) <(sort file1.txt)
```

It's using [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) and [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html#:%7E:text=Process%20substitution%20feeds%20the%20output,the%20stdin%20of%20another%20process.&text=There%20is%20no%20space%20between,would%20give%20an%20error%20message.&text=Bash%20creates%20a%20pipe%20with,%2D%2DfIn%20and%20fOut%2D%2D.).